# Itext7 manipulate Dictionary for Fonts

Tags: itext7

I'd like to ask a question about the relationship between PdfDictionary Fonts and the Stream.

I have this piece of code to add a font into a page's dictionary:

```
private void addFonts(PdfDocument pdfa, String fontPath) throws IOException {        
    PdfDictionary font;
    FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont(fontPath);
    FontProgramFactory.registerFont(fontPath);
    PdfFont fontNew = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontProgram, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, EmbeddingStrategy.PREFER_EMBEDDED);
    fontNew.setSubset(true);
    for (int i = 0; i <= pdfa.getNumberOfPdfObjects(); i++) {
        PdfObject obj = pdfa.getPdfObject(i);
        if (obj != null && !obj.isDictionary()) {
            continue;
        }
        font = (PdfDictionary) obj;
        if (font != null) {
            font.put(PdfName.Font, fontNew.getPdfObject()); 
              System.out.println(font);
        }
         
    }
    pdfa.addFont(fontNew);

}
```

This is the result:

[image]

I ask:
1- Why is the font also added outside the resources? (blue)

2- How can I change the name /F47 (I know that itext generates it automatically) in /F1 (since in the stream there are references to /F1 /F2 /F3) (green)

3- In general how can I generate fonts
"/F1"
"/F2"
"/F3"
and change the references in the stream
[image]

Comment: *"I have this piece of code to add a font into a page's dictionary:"* - Well, that piece of code adds something to ALL indirect dictionary objects in the PDF, not only that of the page. And the way it does so is incorrect even for page dictionaries. Maybe you should explain what you are trying to achieve exactly.

Comment: I would like to embed the already existing pdf Fonts (Helvetica type). I know I have to pass a .ttf using the PdfFontFactory.createFont
But if the pdf exists how do I embed its fonts?